# How to control the loading of static methods of a class

Tags: static, jvm, initialization, classloader

How to control the loading of static methods of a class, say if I have a few independent classes  (A, B, C, D, E..) and if each of these classes have the static blocks, how to control loading of Class A's static block after C or so

Comment: Static block are called when the class is first used. Use them in the order you need the blocks to be called.

Comment: Your use of the term “loading” makes no sense. In Java, only *classes* are loaded, not methods, not “static blocks”. Classes are loaded at the JVMs discretion, they are *initialized* on their first use, which includes the execution of the static initializer. If the classes are, as you say, *independent*, there is no reason to attempt to control their initialization further.

Answer (score 0):

Hacky solution but works!

In your classes A,B,C... add this field

```
static boolean loadMe;
```

Then add the below code in the class that gets loaded first. The class that gets loaded first could be the one that has main() method or the one that is the starting point of your application.

```
static {
    boolead loaded = A.loadMe;
    loaded = B.loadMe;
    ...//In the order that you require
}
```